# Intel i3 2100 processor compatibility motherboard double t

Tags: intel-core-i3

I want to upgrade my desktop computer,  I am planning to buy asus maximus vii Ranger motherboard,  but I am lost in confirming if my present i3 2100 processor would be supported or not,  though they mention 22nm processors. 
 Due to tight budget I will be upgrading entire machine in timely installments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CPU isn't listed on the list of compatible processors.  It also is an entirely different socket **LGA1155** vs **LGA1150**.

Your motherboard only Intel® LGA1150 4th, New 4th & 5th-Generation Core™ i7/Core™ i5/Core™ i3/Pentium®/Celeron® Processors.  If you purchase that motherboard you will need a new CPU.

[List of supported CPUs](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/MAXIMUS_VII_RANGER/HelpDesk_CPU/)
[Intel® Core™ i3-2100 Processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/53422/Intel-Core-i3-2100-Processor-3M-Cache-3_10-GHz)